# What does ”to do so” mean in this sentence?

Tags: word-meaning

As a police officer I was an obvious target and was baited whenever it seemed safe to do so.

In this sentence, does “to do so” mean “to bait me”?
My teacher asked me to rewrite “to do so” to understand exact meanings.

Answer (score 1):

> In this sentence, does “to do so” mean “to bait me”?

Yes, it does.

> As a police officer I was an obvious target and was baited whenever *it seemed safe to do so.*

We can rewrite this as:

> As a police officer I was an obvious target and was baited whenever *they thought they could get away with it.*